# WebkitSpeechRecognition giving network error on chromium browser, Operating System: Ubuntu Linux 23.04

Tags: webspeech-api, webkitspeechrecognition

I am using WebKitSpeechRecognitionAPI, it worked before on another project,but i was mainly running the app on chrome browser, now that I am running the same project on Chromium browser , it starts recording but for only a few seconds.

I tried to record my voice for it to recognize the voice and show it as text, and what i got was an error saying its a network Error.